# Linux ethtool in virtio: how does it control the network speed/duplex?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, driver

I am looking into the code of virtio driver:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/drivers/net/virtio_net.c?id=refs/tags/next-20160211

I am just curious that how does Ethtool control the driver's duplex and speed?

For example, if I specify eth1 speed to 100Mbps by:

> $ ethtool -s eth1 speed 100 duplex full

And indeed, ethtool will tell me the speed of eth1 is 100Mbps. But how actually the driver limits the speed to 100Mbps on a network which actually can offer 40Gbps for example?

> $ ethtool eth1
>
> ```
> Settings for eth1:
> ...
>     Speed: 100Mb/s
>     Duplex: Full
> ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about server configuration, you might want to head over to http://Serverfault.com/. Or, since your question appears to be specific to Linux, http://unix.stackexchange.com/ might be the place to go, with the [appropriate tags](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel). I've submitted a close vote for this question, since it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface does NOT limit the speed. The speed configuration only exists for compatibility reason.

Comment: yes:) I saw the similar thing in Hyperv netvsc. Thanks